# Edits to my code do not show up when running in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I am working on a project which was assigned to me,
they gave me a folder with a ton of classes, docs, and other project related files I'm not too familiar with, and I've been given a separate jar for everything else the project needs.

I have imported the project into eclipse, and can even get a provided test .java I was provided to run correctly, but for some reason any changes I make to the test's code fail to show up when I run it.

I've added code, even commented out lines that would make a big difference in the display, but everything stays the same when I run it.

I have build automatically turned on, and I have even played with it off, turning it back on again, etc.

I fixed all the build path errors by correctly pointing to the external jar, but this still happens.

Has anyone encountered this before and/or do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Could it be that the test class is also contained in the 'everything-else' JAR? In this case they would be twice on the class path, and Eclipse might just use the 'wrong' class.

Comment: Wow, you were pretty spot on there. For some reason I was told to add that jar as an external jar, and that's what was keeping it behind. I had almost given up and moved back to jgrasp for this one.

Comment: Maybe they don't want you to change the test code. :-P But better check whether the code you are _supposed_ to edit is not also contained in the JAR. So, can I put this as an answer, then?

Comment: Yes, you can put that as an answer.

They definitely wanted that file edited. The jar was being used to update libraries and add more documentation, but also contained the source and class of the file I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for such behaviour is that the classes you are editing in your project are also contained in some JAR you are using. Thus, those classes are on the class path *twice*, and Eclipse/Java will load only one of them and ignore the other.

So I suppose that the test classes you are editing (and maybe even the other classes you are supposed to work with!) are contained in the separate JAR for 'everything else' you mentioned.